# Assign a declared Const Name to a var in Delphi

Tags: string, delphi, variables, constants, names

Is there any way to assign a declared const name to a var?, I have the code below where there is some Consts declared as strings, these strings are images in JSON format but depending of selected value I want to display an image or another;

```
unit Images;

interface

Const
    Image1 = '[84,80,70,48,22,84,87,114,97,112,112,101,114,77,117,108,116,105,82,101, 48, 34]';
    Image2 = '[84,80,70,48,22,84,87,114,97,112,112,101,114,77,117,108,116,105,82,101, 90, 47]';
    Image3 = '[84,80,70,48,22,84,87,114,97,112,112,101,114,77,117,108,116,105,82,101, 22, 74]';

.
.
.
.
.
.
.

implementation

end.



unit MainForm;

interface

uses
   Images...

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Picture1: TImage;
    ListBox1: TListBox;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ListBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    procedure AsignJSONToImage(ImageString: String; DisplayImage: TImage);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

procedure TForm1.AsignJSONToImage(ImageString: String; DisplayImage: TImage);
var
  Stream: TStream;
  JsonArray: TJSONArray;
begin
    jsonArray := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(ImageString) as TJSONArray;
    try
        Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
        Stream := TDBXJSONTools.JSONToStream(jsonArray);
        try
            Stream.Position := 0;
            DisplayImage.MultiResBitmap.LoadFromStream(Stream);
        finally
           Stream.Free;
        end;
    finally
        jsonArray.Free;
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
    ListBox1.Items.Add('Image1');
    ListBox1.Items.Add('Image2');
    ListBox1.Items.Add('Image3');
end;

procedure TForm1.ListBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
var
      Item: TListBoxItem;
begin
      Item := Listbox1.Selected;
      AsignJSONToImage(Item.Text, Picture1);  {* Here in the first parameter,I want to pass the name of the const selected in Listbox1 but not the text itself to display the image in Picture1*}
end;

end.
```

I hope you understand what I want to do, many thanks for your appreciated help.

Regards.

Comment: Put the names values in a dictionary, and look them up that way

Comment: That's right !!!, many thanks David

Comment: Only a question, if I have a Dictionary with 400 pair of Keys and Values of strings created in the start of the app like this;

`var
       dict: TDictionary<String, String>;
       i: integer;

begin
       dict := TDictionary<String, String>.Create;
       for i := 1 to 400 do
                dict.Add('Image' + IntToStr(i), '[string values of each image]');
end.`

It would produce a memory leak while app is running in searching for values?

Many thanks.

Comment: Why do you care? Do create it more than once per application? But you should not hold the strings in the dict. Decode them to a stream and store them in the dict `TObjectDictionary<string,TStream>`. And you can have a class around it with some static methods `class procedure AssignImage( ... );`

Comment: @Juande: create the dictionary one time at program startup, then search it when needed, and finally free it at program exit. There will be no leak.

Comment: Dear all, thank you very much for your appreciated help!!